# How to achieve sequence of timeouts with RX?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, .net-4.6

The scenario is as follows: a device communicating over is considered connected if it makes a callback to the server within a short period of time.
I want to create a class that encapsulates the functionality of keeping track of this status. On call to the device, the timeout should be reset. On callback, the connection is confirmed, and the status should be set to *true*, if the callback times out, it should be set to *false*. But the next call should be able to reset the timeout again indifferent to the current status.

I was thinking to achieve this with RX using `swith` and `timeout`. But I don't know why it stops working.

```
public class ConnectionStatus
{
private Subject<bool> pending = new Subject<bool>();
private Subject<bool> connected = new Subject<bool>();

public bool IsConnected { get; private set; }

public ConnectionStatus(CancellationToken token, short timeoutSeconds = 15)
{
    pending.Select(outer => connected.Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutSeconds))) 
        .Switch()
        .Subscribe(_ => IsConnected = true, e => IsConnected = false, token);
}

public void ConfirmConnected()
{
    connected.OnNext(true);
}

public void SetPending()
{
    pending.OnNext(true);
}
}
```

This is the "test case":

```
var c = new ConnectionStatus(default(CancellationToken));

c.SetPending();
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
c.ConfirmConnected();   
c.IsConnected.Dump(); // TRUE, OK

c.SetPending();
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
c.ConfirmConnected();
c.IsConnected.Dump(); // TRUE, OK

c.SetPending();
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
c.IsConnected.Dump(); // FALSE, OK
c.ConfirmConnected(); 
c.IsConnected.Dump(); // FALSE, OK

c.SetPending();
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
c.ConfirmConnected(); 
c.IsConnected.Dump(); // FALSE, NOT OK!
```

I assume that the timeout of the inner observable is also stopping the outer observable. As the `outer =>` lambda is not called anymore. What is the correct way?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `Timeout` essentially causes an Exception blowing up the Rx subscriptions. After the timeout is triggered (as you have it coded), no other notifications will be sent. Rx grammar is that you can have * `OnNext` messages followed by either one `OnCompleted` or one `OnError`. After the `OnError` from the `Timeout` is sent, you'll see no more messages.

You need to have the Timeout message delivered via `OnNext` messages instead of an `OnError` message. In your old code, you turned any `OnError` into a false, and any `OnNext` into a true. Instead you need to embed the proper new `IsConnected` value into `OnNext` messages. Here's how to do that:

```
public ConnectionStatus(CancellationToken token, short timeoutSeconds = 15)
{
    pending.Select(_ => connected
            .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutSeconds))
            .Materialize()
            .Select(n => n.Kind == NotificationKind.OnError && n.Exception.GetType() == typeof(TimeoutException) 
                ? Notification.CreateOnNext(false)
                : n)
            .Dematerialize()
            .Take(1)
        )
        .Switch()
        .Subscribe(b => IsConnected = b, token);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tested your suggestion, and I have found that it needs a  `.FirstOrDefaultAsync()` after `Select`. Without it, the timeout is triggered even after the `connected` mitted the value.  I have found another solution meanwhile: `pending.Select(_ => connected.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutSeconds), 1).FirstOrDefaultAsync()) .Switch().Subscribe(l => IsConnected = l.Count > 0,  token);`

Comment: In what case did you find `FirstOrDefaultAsync` to be required?

Comment: `c.SetPending();
 await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
 c.ConfirmConnected(); 
 c.IsConnected.Dump() /*TRUE, OK*/;
 await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
 c.IsConnected.Dump();` The later should be still TRUE, but it is FALSE without `FirstOrDefaultAsync`.

Comment: Amended answer to fix that bug, and another possible one (exceptions wouldn't be propagated). Your alternate is fine.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an alternative way to produce the stream of `IsConnected` values without using `.TimeOut`:

```
public class ConnectionStatus
{
    private Subject<Unit> pending = new Subject<Unit>();
    private Subject<Unit> connected = new Subject<Unit>();

    public bool IsConnected { get; private set; }

    public ConnectionStatus(CancellationToken token, short timeoutSeconds = 15)
    {
        pending
            .Select(outer =>
                Observable.Amb(
                    connected.Select(_ => true),
                    Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutSeconds)).Select(_ => false)))
            .Switch()
            .Subscribe(isConnected => IsConnected = isConnected, token);
    }

    public void ConfirmConnected()
    {
        connected.OnNext(Unit.Default);
    }

    public void SetPending()
    {
        pending.OnNext(Unit.Default);
    }
}
```

The `Observable.Amb` operator simply takes a value from whichever observable produces a value first - it's preferable to coding with exceptions.